# Как скрыть "панель уведомлений" в приложении Android?

Tags: android, xml, activity, android-manifest, android-constraintlayout

Как скрыть эту информационную панель:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

?

Answer (score 1):

в Вашем activity нужно прописать (код написан на kotlin)

`window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

если версия андроида меньше 4 и ниже, а если выше то

`window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
actionBar?.hide()`

подробнее можете почитать здесь https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Answer (score 0):

Добавить между **super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);** и **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** следующее:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```